# Impetus.js library: TypeError: impetus_1.Impetus is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a Typescript Angular app and I want to add scrolling momentum to a chart.
I previously used [Impetus.js](https://chrisbateman.github.io/impetus/) on other Javascript project without any issues.

However, on this project I am having difficulty getting this integrated. I've tried to import this via

```
import { Impetus } from 'impetus'
```

When I do:

```
var momentum = new Impetus({
  source: myCanvasElement,
  update: function (x, y) {
    myChartingLib.onMouseDrag(x, y);
  }
});
```

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: impetus_1.Impetus is not a constructor.

When looking at the `dist` code, I do see that it ends up creating a `var Impetus = function Impetus(_ref)`.

So admittedly it isn't clear to me how that would translate to a class.

Here's the complete source code of the library, it's not that big:
https://github.com/chrisbateman/impetus/blob/master/src/Impetus.js

Comment: What makes you it has an export named `Impetus`? The export is named `default`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad "default" is a keyword part of the ES6 standard. It is used to export a single function/class/value or to provide a fallback when no curly braces are specified. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export

Comment: Correct. That is how https://github.com/chrisbateman/impetus/blob/master/src/Impetus.js exports `Impetus`. You are trying to import an export named `Impetus` which is incorrect.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so what is the correct import line?

Comment: `import Impetus from 'impetus';`. Note that this is shorthand for `import { default as Impetus } from 'impetus';`. Obviously prefer the shorthand, but it's useful to understand what is happening - that the module does not export anything as `Impetus`